# Large coalitions of lions taking over multiple prides?

Tags: ecology

I have noticed while watching lion documentaries that coalitions with more than 3 males tend to take over multiple prides and have 1 large pride in their territory while coalitions with 3 lions or less tend to take over just 1 pride.

As a very good example the Mapogo brothers(6 lions) take over multiple prides and they even split the territory between a coalition of 4 and a coalition of 2.

On the other side of the spectrum Tau and Banda are just 2 lions in a coalition. They take over just 1 pride with 3 lionesses in heat and no cubs. Tau does it by instinct and Banda is strategic.

Why is there so much of a difference between the small coalitions that take over just 1 pride and the large coalitions that take over multiple prides? Do large coalitions do better when they take over multiple prides from less aggression? Do small coalitions do better when they take over just 1 pride from more and closer defenses against other male lions?

Comment: In which documentaries did you learn about this? I want to learn more :)

Comment: the size of the territory expands with each takeover so a larger takeover such as the Mapogo they split to protect the territory they have inherited.